# R Code Runs Fine in RStudio but not in Visual Studio

Tags: r, visual-studio, rtvs

I just ran this in RStudio and it works fine.

```
Gender <- c("Female","Female","Male","Male")
Restaurant <- c("Yes","No","Yes","No")
Count <- c(220, 780, 400, 600)
DiningSurvey <- data.frame(Gender, Restaurant, Count)
DiningSurvey
```

Then I try to run it in Visual Studio and it does nothing at all.

If I go to Test > Run > All Tests, I get this: 'There were successful build errors. Would you like to continue and run tests from the last successful build?'  There is no last build and no matter what I try, this doesn't work.  IF I hit any function key, including F5, F11, or whatever, this doesn't work!!  How can I run R code in Visual Studio?  It seems like this should be super-simple, but it is very, very, very difficult.

Thanks.

Comment: You might want to mark one of these correct. Or say why neither is.

Answer (score 4):

In general, R in VS works same a R in RStudio. In other words, F5 does not work since R is not a compiled language and does not have predefined entry point. For example, for debugging you set a breakpoint, then attach debugger, then source file and then call the desired function from R interactive window.

Answer (score 1):

To run R in Visual Studio, you need the R Tools for Visual Studio (RTVS) plugin.

You can download this at http://microsoft.github.io/RTVS-docs/

This will turn Visual Studio into a capable client that knows how to deal with R.

---

Once you've installed RTVS, the easiest way to get started is to create a new R project:

\File\New\Project...\New R Project

This will create a new project with templates for R and Rmd files.

You can send code from an R file to the "R Interactive" window by pressing Ctrl+Enter.

You can see this in action by watching the video at https://youtu.be/KPS0ytrt9SA

Comment: Thanks, but my question was how do you run the code.  I have the plugin.  It doesn't seem to run any code.  I can't debug code.  I can't run code.  I can't do anything at all.  How does it work?