# R file runs great in R studio, not VSCode

Tags: r, string, visual-studio-code

Quick backstory:

- I've already done quite a few other R scripts in VSCode.  I have the R extension, I've knitted .rmd's, etc. etc...
- So in other words, unlike the solutions [posted here which dealt more with getting R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36825081/r-code-runs-fine-in-rstudio-but-not-in-visual-studio) to work in the first place (in visual studio at least), I've already got R working for most things within VSCode.

So I have an R file that I'll put the code to below, but when I open the file in RStudio, it works great!  It creates a jdbc connection, queries a database using some SQL, creates a dataframe, etc...

When I close that file, and then open it in VSCode, it'll run MOST of the r code within it, but when it goes to do the query, I get this sql error:

"JDBC ERROR: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis"

And its the exact same file!  I'd google what ORA-00907 means for SQL and how to fix it.... but the code DOES work in Rstudio?

One other thing I noticed is the problem does NOT happen when I run the file as a whole from within VsCode, i.e.:

```
source("BlackBox.R")
```

If I do that, I'll step through everything and save out the results of the query as a .csv like I want it to.  But if I OPEN the file and go through line by line, or try to run the whole thing, or anything.... it won't work.

Code below (with names changed to protect the innocent):

```
library(tidyverse)
Sys.setenv(JAVA_HOME="C:\\Program Files\\TIBCO\\Jaspersoft Studio-6.6.0\\features\\jre.win32.win32.x86_64.feature_1.8.0.u171\\jre") 

options(java.parameters="-Xmx2g")  


replacement <- function(category = "LC_ALL") {
  if (identical(category, "LC_MESSAGES"))
    return("")
  category <- match(category, .LC.categories)
  if (is.na(category)) 
    stop("invalid 'category' argument")
  .Internal(Sys.getlocale(category))
}

base <- asNamespace("base")
environment(replacement) <- base
unlockBinding("Sys.getlocale", base)
assign("Sys.getlocale", replacement, envir = base)
lockBinding("Sys.getlocale", base)

library(rJava)
rJava::.jinit()

library(RJDBC)  

jdbcDriver <- JDBC(driverClass="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver", classPath="C:/Users/johnDoe/OneDrive - Company/Documents/Data/jar files/ojdbc8.jar")  
jdbcConnection <- dbConnect(jdbcDriver, "jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcps)(HOST=website.com)(PORT=2879))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=pdblhs)))", "name", "password")  

Subjects <- dbGetQuery(jdbcConnection,
"WITH usa AS (
    SELECT subj_access.protocol_id
        , subj_access.protocol_subject_id
    FROM website.sv_user_pcl_permission priv_check
        JOIN website.sv_user_pcs_access subj_access ON priv_check.protocol_id = subj_access.protocol_id AND priv_check.contact_id = subj_access.contact_id
    WHERE priv_check.function_name = 'CRPT-Subject Visits'
        AND priv_check.contact_id = '1234')
, subjects AS (
    SELECT Protocol_id, Protocol_no, Protocol_subject_id,subject_no, sequence_number, status,status_date
    FROM website.RV_SUBJECT_STATUS 
)
, all_visit AS (
    SELECT protocol_subject_id, visit_name, visit_date, planned_visit_date, visit_desc FROM website.rv_sub_calendar WHERE visit_status = 'Planned' and visit_date > ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, 0) 
)
, max_visit AS (
    SELECT protocol_subject_id, visit_name, visit_date, planned_visit_date, visit_desc FROM LHS_ONCORE_PROD.all_visit WHERE (visit_date, protocol_subject_id) IN (SELECT MIN(visit_date) visit_date, protocol_subject_id FROM all_visit GROUP BY protocol_subject_id)-- 
)
, followup AS (
    SELECT protocol_subject_id, off_studydate, off_study_reason FROM website.rv_subject_follow_up
)
SELECT subjects.protocol_id
    , subjects.protocol_no
    , subjects.protocol_subject_id
    , subjects.subject_no
    , subjects.sequence_number
    , subjects.status
    , subjects.status_date
    , max_visit.visit_date 
    , max_visit.planned_visit_date
    , max_visit.visit_name 
    , max_visit.visit_desc 
    , followup.off_studydate
    , followup.off_study_reason
FROM usa
    INNER JOIN subjects ON subjects.Protocol_subject_id = usa.protocol_subject_id
    LEFT JOIN max_visit ON max_visit.protocol_subject_id = usa.protocol_subject_id
    LEFT JOIN followup ON followup.Protocol_subject_id = subjects.Protocol_subject_id
")


# Close connection
dbDisconnect(jdbcConnection) ##Closes it.


setwd("A:/Project Documents/R Database connections/place")
write_csv(Subjects,"Subject.csv")
```

Any ideas?  At least where to look?

**Update:**

It's something to do with the spacing in VSCode.  For instance if I run this simple command on one line, it'll recognize it as a new object and save it into the environment:
[image]

But if I run this command thats split over two lines, it'll trap me in an endless loop of looking for a right parenthesis or something:

[image]

And when I highlight several lines from the query, it'll show me different spacing/indentations in the beginning of each line even though they all look the same:
[image]

Comment: Minor thing to help narrow down the problem - create your query as a string object outside of `dbGetQuery()`, that is `qry <- "WITH usa AS ..."`, then use `Subjects <- dbGetQuery(jdbcConnection, qry)`. Running one line at a time, that will hopefully help narrow down if the issue is in the query string itself or something that happens with the `dbGetQuery` command.

Comment: I'd also try hard to make a minimal example. Make a new script, set up the db connection, and see if you can run `"SELECT * subj_access.protocol_id FROM website.sv_user_pcs_access subj_access limit 10"` Gradually add more and more complexity to your script to find when it breaks.

Comment: One other quick thing to try: sometimes I've had trouble with SQL comments in strings. I see you have one line of query code ending in `--`. Try removing that (and any other SQL comments I might have missed).

Comment: So... update.  the -- didn't change anything.   I did take my entire query and make it qry< "my long query bla bla bla" and noticed something interesting:   In R if I run that line, it'll work and realize there's a new object called Qry with all that stuff in it.   

In VSCode if I try to run that line the terminal keeps asking me to put a right parenthesis on it and no matter how many I do it'll keep me in an endless loop.  It seems to be some weird right parenthesis VSCode thing

Comment: @GregorThomas added some new information/screenshots.  It looks like something to do with the spacing that VSCode recognizes

Comment: You could find/replace tabs with spaces. But that's good  news! Something in the string definition seems easier to solve than something in the querying.

Comment: Again, I'd try to narrow it down to as small a reproducible example as you can. Can you find a 2-line string that exhibits the problem? (Now that you've narrowed it down this far you'll increase your chance of good answers if you edit your question to remove all the stuff we now know is irrelevant and focus on the string/spacing.)